# excerpt in template for specific page

Tags: posts, categories, templates, excerpt

I have created a child theme for [Twenty Thirteen](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentythirteen/).  I want to have a separate page called `authors-blog` that uses a template called `blogSummaryPage` that displays excerpts from the category "`blog`".  I already know how to get the categories I want, but I can't figure out how to display excerpts on this one specific page using this template.

It would be nice just to be able to edit the `content.php` for the `search`, `archive`, `single page`, etc., but I'm not sure how to target that specific page.

Here's the page I want to excerpt:  http://dakreilein.com/development/authors-blog/

Comment: So to be clear, the question is how to use this template for one specific page?  I'm not sure if you are asking how to get the page to use that template or how to get the excerpts with that template.

Comment: I am already using a template for one specific page and I want it to act like the search.php -- except I don't want to display the "Search Results for:   ".  In the content.php file, the excerpt is done for the search page (if is_search), the archive page and I forget what the other page is.  I could get the result I wanted if I could somehow check for the page-name or page id or something like that in content.php.

Comment: Oh -- and I am checking for a category of "blog" to limit the posts only to that category.

Comment: So the answer to the question is....?

Comment: No, I know how to use a template for a single page.  I'm asking how to get excerpts on THAT specific page that uses that template.  Does that answer your question?  And the caps is not shouting but emphasis only.

Comment: How to get excerpt on a template? the_excerpt()

Answer (score 0):

The following code will query the "blog" category for the latest three published posts and loop through these results to display the excerpt from each.

```
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'blog',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
);

$blog_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $blog_posts->have_posts() ):
    while ( $blog_posts->have_posts() ): 
        $blog_posts->the_post();

        // Do stuff with each post
        echo get_the_excerpt() . "<br>";

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

WordPress Codex is a great resource for WP development.  The WP_Query class is incredibly powerful and well-documented here:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters